# How can i format joda DateTime in this style "yyMMddHHmmss"?

Tags: jodatime, joda-convert

i tried doing this:

```
    DateTime dt=new DataTime(DatetimeZone.UTC);
    DateTimeFormatter diff=DatTimeFormat.forPattern("yyMMddHHmmss");
    DateTime jtime=diff.ParseDateTime(dt.toString());
```

But am getting illegal argument exception.
please help me to resolve this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this;

```
    DateTime today = new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    System.out.println(today.toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z")));
```

or this;

```
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
    String str = fmt.print(dt);
    System.out.println(str);
```

Also from JODA Javadoc; toString() method for DateTime outputs the date in ISO8601.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot and came up with this solution

```
dt.toString("yyMMddHHmmss");
```